# What are some high school algebra books that are similar to Mary Dolciani's two volume series?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have come across them in a thrift shop and completely fell in love with the method employed by her. Almost nothing is taken for granted and everything from the definition of subtraction to the addition propert of equality is first demonstrated (or proved) before being employed.

I have picked up Serge Lang's *Basic Mathematics* with the hope of reviewing Dolciani's exposition of high school algebra through someone else's words but the book failed me as it doesn't go deeper than your usual half-baked modern algebra book.

I don't want to move on to reading the first chapters of some abstract algebra books as I don't know the notation much.

Do you guys know of any other book similar to Dolciani's in method of exposition?

Comment: The Dolciani books are in print.  Here's the Algebra 2 book: https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Trigonometry-Structure-Method-Book/dp/039567610X

Comment: I already have it. My question was whether there were books similar to them.

Comment: I know.  That's why I posted a comment, not an answer.